# What data type I have to use for DB2 Varchar1000 column to Excel during data conversion task

Tags: ssis

I have a DB2 column which is varchar(1000), I have to written a package to send data from DB2 to Excel. So, What datatype I have to use?

I tried DT_STR to DT_WSTR with 1000 and also tried DT_TEXT, but when it comes to EXCEL task, it shows - Cannot convert from non unicode to unicode.

I need to know datatypes to be used for smooth run.

Comment: Have u choose code page 1252?

Comment: @BeiBeiZHU what?